# Internet Explorer refuses to use custom fonts in websites

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, truetype-fonts, embedded-fonts

I'm in a middle of creating a new website where I would like to use custom fonts. I have already spent a day figuring out why Internet Explorer doesn't recognize this custom font and use 'Arial' (default) instead.

Then I was curious whether my copy of Internet Explorer 9 is wrong or  there is still some errors on my website that it became clear. The problem is in my machine. Custom fonts appear in other computers. Here's a test: http://bit.ly/TiIGzF

What I have tried already: uninstall and downgrade back to IE8 (still no custom fonts), install again IE9 (no custom fonts), install all the windows updates (no luck), I went through all the settings but found nothing relevant. I'm stuck. I can't make it work and I dont want to reinstall the whole Windows.

Any suggestions? What am I missing?

Comment: Tried a complete browser reset from `Internet Options / Advanced tab`?

Comment: It did not work unfortunately :( I also tried setting the Document Mode and Browser Mode without luck.

Answer (score 2):

Press Alt-T to get the Tools menu. Choose Internet Options. Choose Accessibility. Make sure no checkboxes are checked. In the second screenshot they are checked. This might cause the problem. Note: I am using Internet Explorer 10 here, maybe the menu is slightly different.

[image: Internet Options]
[image: Accessibility]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately all those checkboxes were empty. :(